# SQl query help in grouping

Tags: mysql, transpose

An SQL table schema,

```
time, country, activer_users
```

If I just want to show the total number of active users over time, Below simple slect wil do that

```
SELECT time, sum(active_users) as activer_users GROUP BY  time ORDER BY time
```

returned data will be like,

```
[{
  "time": 1585878969,
  "active_users": 2300
},....]
```

If I want active_users over time by country, then

```
SELECT time, country, sum(active_users) as activer_users GROUP BY  time ORDER BY time, country
```

returned data will be like,

```
   [{
      "time": 1585878969,
      "active_users": 1300,
      "country": "India"
    }, {
      "time": 1585878969,
      "active_users": 1000,
      "country": "China"
    }....]
```

I want data in the below format,

```
[{
     "time": 1585878969,
     "India": 1300,
     "China": "1000"
}....]
```

Is this possible, to create dynamic columns from the value of a field and its value based on another field..

if suchthing is possible, what should be the query for that

Comment: This is pivot which is not implemented in MySQL. Emulate (stored procedure, dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Other helpful users may correct me, but I think is not possible altering MySQL responses like this. MySQL always responds in a COLUMN-VALUE way, so you would have to create a column e.g. "China" and store this data in there to get a native response like this.